# In Eclipse, in a dynamic web project that is dependent on a maven project, how do I pick up jars from the maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies

In Eclipse, I have two projects:

> archangel.core - a Maven project
>
> ArchangelWEB - a Dynamic Web Project (built for Tomcat).

The first, archangel.core has all of the base code and uses Maven to resolve dependencies. The second is the Web addition on top of the core project. This only has code specific to presentation/view. I want to keep them separate because I may have other projects in the future that will rely on the core, and I don't want the core project to have Web Library dependencies.

Right now, in ArchangelWEB's build path, I have the archangel.core project, and I also have archangel.core in its Deployment Assembly. This allows me to refer to code from archangel.core in ArchangelWEB without any build or runtime problems.

One of archangel.core's dependencies is apache-commons-lang. Within archangel.core, I can reference classes like `ExceptionUtils`. However, I cannot automatically reference this jar dependency from ArchangelWEB. If I try to `import` class from apache-commons-lang in ArchangelWEB, it doesn't know what I am talking about.

What is the best way to import/reference dependency jars from a maven project into this other project (my Dynamic Web Project), which uses the maven project as a dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic Web Projects resolves dependency only by manually placing the Jars in the WEB-INF/libs folder. There is no other way.

So you need to place the dependent jars of your Dynamic Web Project into the libs folder manually.
Don't forget to do Right-click the Jars in Lib -> Add to Build path after adding them

This is why we use maven these days instead of the old Dynamic Web Projects.

Comment: Thanks - when I export ArchangelWEB as a war, If I go into WEB-INF/lib, I see archangel.core.jar present (because I put archangel.core in ArchangelWEB's deployment assembly). The assumption that I made was that archangel.core.jar would _include_ all jar dependencies within the jar itself, but what I found when I exported it as a WAR is that archangel.core.jar only had the code from the Maven Java Project. Now I realize what you are saying, and why we would use Maven to build a Web Project instead.